# simple issue on url mapping with spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I develop with spring 4.1. I try to map my urls with the controllers

Here is an extract of my web.xml file

```
<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

here is an extract of my spring xml file

```
        <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="orm,orm.impl,web.controller.impl,web.view" />
```

Here is an extract of my  controller file

```
    package web.controller.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import service.CommonManagementService;
import web.view.QuestionItem;
import domain.Question;

@Controller
public class ComboController  {



    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("commonManagementService")
    private CommonManagementService commonManagementService;

    public CommonManagementService getCommonManagementService() {
        return this.commonManagementService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/unsecure/getQuestion", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getQuestion(ModelMap model) {
        LOGGER.info("debut methode getQuestion");
        final List<QuestionItem> results = new ArrayList<QuestionItem>();
        final List<Question> questions = this.commonManagementService.getQuestions();
        for (final Question question : questions) {
            results.add(new QuestionItem(question.getQuestion(), question.getId().toString()));
        }
        final Map<String, Object> modelToPass = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("items", results);
        LOGGER.info("fin methode getQuestion");
        return new ModelAndView("jsonResultView", model);

    }

    public void setCommonManagementService(
            CommonManagementService commonManagementService) {
        this.commonManagementService = commonManagementService;
    }
}
```

The name of my application is tennisArc1600 and when I try to send the url 
http://localhost:8080/tennisArc1600/unsecure/getQuestion or http://localhost:8080/unsecure/getQuestion
I get the error 404 the ressource is not available

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Use in web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

And then declare

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

or alternatively

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

in your Spring web configuration

Answer (score 0):

Hello Test Testini and thank you for your answer.

I succeded in reaching my controller. here is my configuration

web.xml

```
<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="domain,orm,orm.impl" /> -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:persistence.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:securities.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:mail.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:views.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="basename" value="views"/>
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
        location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/" cache-period="10000" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="orm,orm.impl,web.controller.impl,web.view" />

</beans>
```

my controller

```
    package web.controller.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import service.CommonManagementService;
import utils.Result;
import web.view.QuestionItem;
import domain.Question;

@Controller
public class ComboController  {



    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("commonManagementService")
    private CommonManagementService commonManagementService;

    public CommonManagementService getCommonManagementService() {
        return this.commonManagementService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/unsecure/getQuestion.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getQuestion(ModelMap model) {
        LOGGER.info("debut methode getQuestion");
        final List<QuestionItem> results = new ArrayList<QuestionItem>();
        final List<Question> questions = this.commonManagementService.getQuestions();
        for (final Question question : questions) {
            results.add(new QuestionItem(question.getQuestion(), question.getId().toString()));
        }
        final Map<String, Object> modelToPass = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("items", results);
        model.put("results", new ArrayList<Result>());
        LOGGER.info("fin methode getQuestion");
        return new ModelAndView("jsonResultView", model);

    }

    public void setCommonManagementService(
            CommonManagementService commonManagementService) {
        this.commonManagementService = commonManagementService;
    }
}
```

Thanks again

Comment: hi @flamant, you are welcome, in general if you think an answer solved your problem/question you should accept it as question answer.